# UTF-8 constexpr std::string_view from static constexpr std::array not valid on MSVC

Tags: c++, constexpr

The title is a bit wordy, the code demonstrates the problem better:

```
// Equivalent to क़
constexpr auto arr = std::array<char, 3>{static_cast<char>(0340),
                                         static_cast<char>(0245),
                                         static_cast<char>(0230)};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = std::string_view{"क़"};
    constexpr auto b = std::string_view{arr.data(), arr.size()};

    static_assert(a.size() == 3);
    static_assert(b.size() == 3);
    static_assert(a[0] == b[0]);
    static_assert(a[1] == b[1]);
    static_assert(a[2] == b[2]);

    static_assert(a == b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The last `static_assert` fails on [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/4dnTvG6z1), but is fine on [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/679KP17MW) and clang.  At first I thought it might have been a Windows thing not supporting UTF-8 well, but it works fine at runtime:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = std::string_view{"क़"};
    constexpr auto b = std::string_view{arr.data(), arr.size()};

    return a == b ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Adding `/utf-8` to the compiler args makes no difference.  It does appear to be a Unicode/UTF-8 issue, because a plain ASCII string works:

```
// foo
constexpr auto arr = std::array<char, 3>{'f', 'o', 'o'};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = std::string_view{"foo"};
    constexpr auto b = std::string_view{arr.data(), arr.size()};

    static_assert(a == b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This feels like a compiler bug, but I'm no language lawyer so it could be that I'm doing something I'm not supposed to - can anybody see what?

Comment: Unicode and 'old fashioned' C++ `char` strings don't always mix well! Your code works if you use `std::u8string_view` and `char8_t`.

Comment: Reduced test case: https://godbolt.org/z/K6e93TvdW It seems that MSVC is internally (at compile-time) representing the string literal with _unsigned_ character values and the builtin (used in `operator==`) compares the string literal contents with their values in the unsigned range with the array's values in a signed range (because `char` is signed) instead of using actual memory representation. This doesn't look like it is supposed to be done like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler bug which Microsoft devs seem to already be aware of, see [this bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2050) against the standard library.

It seems that comparing narrow string literals with bytes outside the [0,127] range against non string literals currently fails at compile-time, because the built-in `__builtin_memcmp` has a bug.

The issue is already a year old, but I couldn't find an update on it.